# My post request of todos1 is showing bad request?

Tags: node.js

can anyone tell me my post request for todos1 is showing bad request my app1 app is absolutely fine and my code is not showing any error on running node server but when i did run it in postman it is showing bad request 400 but sending right data to my database it means that my req.send function is wrong somewhere can anyone tell me where i am wrong???

```
const lodash=require('lodash');
var express=require('express');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var {app1}=require('./todos');
var {ObjectId}=require('mongodb');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp');
var port=process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app=express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.post('/todos',(req,res)=>
{
    var todo=new app1({
        text:req.body.text,
        email:req.body.email
    });
    todo.save().then((docs)=>
    {
        res.send(docs);
    },(err)=>
    {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});

app.get('/todos',(req,res)=>
{
    app1.find().then((todos)=>{
        res.send({
            todos
        })
    },(err)=>
    {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});

app.get('/todos/:id',(req,res)=>
{
    var id=req.params.id;
    if(!ObjectId.isValid(id))
    {  var text1='No id is found';
        res.status(404).send({text1});
    }

        app1.findById(id).then((todos)=>
        {
            if(todos)
            {
                res.send(todos);
            }
            else
            {
                res.status(404).send();
            }
        },(err)=>
        {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });
});
app.patch('/todos/:id',(req,res)=>
{
    var id=req.params.id;
    var body=lodash.pick(req.body,['text','completed']);
    if(!ObjectId.isValid(id))
    {
        var text1="no id is found";
        return res.status(404).send({text1});
    }
    if(lodash.isBoolean(body.completed) && (body.completed))
    {
     body.completedBy=new Date().getTime();
    }
    else
    {
        body.completed=false;
        body.completedBy=null;
    }

    app1.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{$set:body},{new:true}).then((todos)=>
    {
        if(todos)
        {
            return res.send(todos);
        }
        else
        {
            res.status(404).send();
        }
    },(err)=>
    {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});

app.delete('/todos/:id',(req,res)=>
{
    var id=req.params.id;
    if(!ObjectId.isValid(id))
    {
        var text1='No id is found';
        return res.status(404).send({text1});
    }
    app1.findByIdAndRemove(id).then((todos)=>
    {
        if(todos)
        {
            return res.send(todos);
        }
        else
        {
            res.status(404).send();
        }
    },(err)=>
    {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
    }
);
app.post('/todos1',(req,res)=>
{
    var body=lodash.pick(req.body,['email','password','text']);
    var user=new app1(body);
    user.save().then(()=>
    {
        return user.generateAuthToken();
        }).then((token)=>
        {
            res.header('x-auth',token).send(user);
        }).catch((e)=>
        {
            res.status(400).send(e);
        });
});

app.listen(port,()=>
{
    console.log(`Starting port ${port}`);
});

module.exports={app};
```

Comment: Just log `err` before `res.status(400).send(err);` to know what's going on. The promise is failing and is getting to the `catch` block

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what you mean, but if `user.save()` is working and you're seeing the new document in your database, then the `user.generateAuthToken()` must be failing.

Postman should show you a response with the error, but if it doesn't, just log the error on the server side.